# Ruby application does not receive UDP packet from different host

Tags: ruby, network-programming, udp

Sending a UDP packet from Ruby client to Ruby server using the server address 192.168.1.30 works as expected, but only if client and server are on the same host. If the client runs on a different machine, the UDP packet finds its way to the server, but my server process won't notice.

Server:

```
require 'socket'
sock = UDPSocket.new()
sock.bind('', 8999)
p sock
while true do
    p sock.recvfrom(2000)
end
sock.close
```

Client:

```
require 'socket'
sock = UDPSocket.new
p sock.send("foo", 0, "192.168.1.30", 8999)
sock.close
```

After starting the server, `netstat -n --udp --listen` approves that the socket is open:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address     Foreign Address         State      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8999      0.0.0.0:*
```

After running the client twice (on 192.168.1.30 and on .23), server output shows only one incoming packet, missing the one from 192.168.1.23:

```
#<UDPSocket:fd 7, AF_INET, 0.0.0.0, 8999>
["foo", ["AF_INET", 52187, "192.168.1.30", "192.168.1.30"]]
```

while Wireshark indicates that two packets were noticed

```
No  Time        Source          Destination     Proto Length Info
1   0.000000000 192.168.1.30    192.168.1.30    UDP   47     52187 → 8999 Len=3
2   2.804243569 192.168.1.23    192.168.1.30    UDP   62     39800 → 8999 Len=3
```

Which probably obvious detail am I missing?

Comment: Why is it showing as bound to `.1.255`? You should be able to reply to the address specified in the received packet, but I don't see that code here.

Comment: Sorry, pasted output from an earlier attempt so solve the problem. Corrected that. It shows `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Does the server have a firewall running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you have any firewall rules active:

```
sudo iptables -L
sudo ufw status
```

Comment: `ufw allow proto udp from any to 192.168.1.30 port 8999` did the trick. Phew. Wasn't aware ufw was running.